Javascript Function using a parameter defined in the future
I'm doing a question that appears in 10:10:02 of this video https://youtu.be/EerdGm-ehJQ?t=36602 (Challenge exercise 12f)
The question is as follows:

Click a button in HTML
Add a message on the screen
Start a 'setTimeout' for 2 seconds, at the end of the 2 seconds, remove the message
But within that 2 second timeout, press the button again
The timeout has to refresh (using clearTimeout) so the timer will continue on for more than the original 2 seconds.

I figured out the solution but I don't understand how it works.
my code is as follows:


let timeoutID;

function updateMessage() {
  const message = document.querySelector('.js-message')

  message.innerHTML = 'Added'

  clearTimeout(timeoutID)

  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    message.innerHTML = ''
  }, 2000)

}
<button onclick="
  updateMessage();
  ">Add to cart</button>


<p class="js-message"></p>



When the clearTimeout(timeoutID) line is ran, it seems to me that the parameter that is being inputted into clearTimeout is defined on the next bit of code below. how is clearTimeout reaching onto the 2 lines of code below and then going back and running itself?
I see that I've put 'let timeoutID' in the first line of the script, but I'm not assigning anything to it. I dont understand this part.

The clearTimeout is cleaning up previous timeouts that may still be running (as the timeoutID variable is reused), it will not clean up the timeout defined on the following lines (until the updateMessage function is called again)

This is aka a “debouncing function”. See also this

I would recommend looking into some debugging tools and stepping through your code, it should help you understand what order things occur in.

The clearTimeout(timeoutID) works because timeoutID is declared outside the updateMessage function, so it keeps its value across multiple calls of updateMessage. When clearTimeout(timeoutID) runs, it stops the previous timeout (if there was one), then a new setTimeout is started and assigned to timeoutID. This way, each time you press the button, it resets the timer by clearing the old timeout and starting a fresh 2-second countdown.

ohhh. so it basically goes like this: the first time that clearTimeout(timeoutID) is ran, it doesnt do anything, because i've only 'let timeoutID' as nothing.
Then the SECOND time i run clearTimeout(timeoutID) it is clearing the timeoutID that was defined 2 lines below?

Yes, you got it! The first time you call clearTimeout(timeoutID), it does nothing because timeoutID is still undefined. Only after you assign a value to timeoutID from setTimeout()does it reference a valid timeout. So, the second call toclearTimeout(timeoutID)` will successfully clear that timeout.
